# Playing videos on Google Colab

Tags: python, opencv, youtube, google-colaboratory

I tried to use the following codes to play YouTube videos on Google Colab,

```py
!pip install pytube==9.1.0
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ncJV0tMAjE&t=72s')
```

The title of yt object is,

```py
print(yt.title)
>> 作業2 第二題 強健控制：結構化不確定參數的Riccati equation
```

Then, I imported cv2.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('作業2 第二題 強健控制：結構化不確定參數的Riccati equation.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, I always got an error message as,

```
Runtime died. Automatically restarting.
```

What should I do?

Comment: cv2 uses native GUI interface as it's backend. while colab is a totally different environment

Comment: @tintin so...cv2 may entirely fail to work on colab, right?

Comment: cv2 works fine except the GUI part

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to get the embed code of your video.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lTTZ8PkQ_Pk" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

Comment: this didnot work for me. IPython.display.YouTubeVideo module worked for me

Answer (score 11):

If you want to play a youtube video on google colab,

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo('-ncJV0tMAjE')
```

**'-ncJV0tMAjE'** is from the URL(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ncJV0tMAjE) after **'watch?v='**

Answer (score 0):

That is because cv2.imshow destroys your session in google colab, instead of that you have to import cv2_imshow: from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow, but cv2_imshow just takes one argument and that is your frame or image.