# Upload videos to Youtube on Google Colab

Tags: python, youtube, upload, google-colaboratory

Using Google Drive on Google Colab has been made easy.
But I did not find any simplified way to upload to Youtube on Google Colab.
I tried the code at [Youtube-Upload](https://github.com/tokland/youtube-upload/), but I was not successful. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
from IPython.display import YouTubeVideo
YouTubeVideo('ZDa-Z5JzLYM')
```

or this

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML('<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>')
```

I am not sure what you mean by 'uploading' but the above two ways are embedding the video in colab which are provided by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52050860/playing-videos-on-google-colab/55532036#55532036).